# Can a web site running on Windows Azure connect to a socket hosted outside the Azure cloud?

Tags: sockets, azure, tcp

I am curious if it is possible (as well as how) to connect FROM a website hosted by/in Windows Azure TO an outside server (IP and port) using a TCP socket.  I have no ability to change the outside infrastructure, but could change the way I access it - for example, maybe rewriting the request to connect using socket.io or something else (which may or may not solve the problem).  But since I already have it working outside of Azure, it would be nice if it was simply a configuration to enable my web site to call to this outside system, which only exposes its functionality through a socket connection.  Thanks!

Comment: You should probably just test this by trying to connect to a website with a non standard port.  This should confirm that Azure can allow an outgoing connection using TCP.  I'm sure you know this but: once the socket is open the communications go both ways, which would allow you to control your Azure instance after the socket was opened.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? My tests fail